# Multiple Background Jobs Redis Queue

Tags: heroku, redis, fastapi, rq

I am trying to implement a fast API app in Heroku.
A user has the option to send a keyword with the API endpoint.
This triggers a background job (web scraping with the keyword).
If there are multiple user triggering the job at a similar time I manage this with a Redis Queue.

Right now the jobs get executed sequentially. So the second user has to wait until the first job gets finished.
I want to process multiple jobs simultaneously with one heroku dyno.
I think the dyno is not running close to full capacity and I don't want to scale my dynos because of costs.

Is this possible to process multiple background jobs with Redis Queue in one heroku dyno?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve it?